# How can I identify images not used in an active Wordpress theme?

Tags: command-line, themes, wordpress

I use Wordpress in Ubuntu 18.04. My active theme generates 55 additional images along with the original image, because there are many demo versions.

Is there a command to detect what image sizes are really used in the active version of the theme?

That would enable me to remove the unused image sizes.

```
serverpilot@server1:~/apps/mshare/public/wp-content/uploads/2019$ ll
total 59676
drwxr-xr-x+  7 serverpilot serverpilot     4096 May 31 22:00 ./
drwxr-xr-x+ 16 serverpilot serverpilot     4096 Jun  3 08:55 ../
drwxr-xr-x+  2 serverpilot serverpilot    36864 May 11 09:59 01/
drwxr-xr-x+  2 serverpilot serverpilot    65536 May  9 22:19 03/
drwxr-xr-x+  2 serverpilot serverpilot 11481088 Apr 30 21:49 04/
drwxr-xr-x+  2 serverpilot serverpilot 41955328 May 31 21:59 05/
drwxr-xr-x+  2 serverpilot serverpilot  7405568 Jun  8 18:02 06/
```

These are the sizes of the images:

```
1024x576.jpg 
110x110.jpg 
1122x631.jpg 
1122x720.jpg 
1152x648.jpg 
150x150.jpg 
171x96.jpg 
180x120.jpg 
180x135.jpg 
192x108.jpg 
192x144.jpg 
192x192.jpg 
192x96.jpg 
220x220.jpg 
265x186.jpg 
300x169.jpg 
311x311.jpg 
313x176.jpg 
364x156.jpg 
364x205.jpg 
384x192.jpg 
384x216.jpg 
384x288.jpg 
384x384.jpg 
440x440.jpg 
531x371.jpg 
561x316.jpg 
561x421.jpg 
608x342.jpg 
728x312.jpg 
728x409.jpg 
728x410.jpg 
758x379.jpg 
758x426.jpg 
768x432.jpg 
85x48.jpg 
90x67.jpg ΦΩΤΟΓΡΑΦΙΕΣ-ΠΟΥ-ΤΡΑΒΗΧΤΗΚΑΝ-ΛΙΓΑ-ΔΕΥΤΕΡΟΛΕΠΤΑ-ΠΡΙΝ-ΣΥΜΒΕΙ-ΤΟ-ΜΟΙΡΑΙΟ.jpg (original uploaded)
```

Comment: Maybe others understand the question but I would need more details on the file names and sizes you want to remove. This way some sort of pattern could be established to select unwanted files.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i will create some screenshots

Comment: here is a link of a demo version i used in my site: https://bimber.bringthepixel.com/wall/

Comment: here is a screenshot of some image sizes: https://prnt.sc/nzarbl

Comment: maybe in the theme i need 20 image sizes, but it create 55 sizes

Comment: It is best to use `ll` command on the directory containing the files. Then copy and paste text output into your question. Screenshots of file names and sizes is frowned upon in **Ask Ubuntu**.

Comment: all those sizes need a lot of disc server spase

Comment: Also before an automated solution is created to mass delete files in your `ll` output try to delete one file manually first and ensure it doesn't break your app.

Comment: the output of ls is an example of all the image sizes, the files are in greek lang, but you can see the created sizes

Comment: 1024x576.jpg
110x110.jpg
1122x631.jpg
1122x720.jpg
1152x648.jpg
150x150.jpg
171x96.jpg
180x120.jpg
180x135.jpg
192x108.jpg
192x144.jpg
192x192.jpg
192x96.jpg
220x220.jpg
265x186.jpg
300x169.jpg
311x311.jpg
313x176.jpg
364x156.jpg
364x205.jpg
384x192.jpg
384x216.jpg
384x288.jpg
384x384.jpg
440x440.jpg
531x371.jpg
561x316.jpg
561x421.jpg
608x342.jpg
728x312.jpg
728x409.jpg
728x410.jpg
758x379.jpg
758x426.jpg
768x432.jpg
85x48.jpg
90x67.jpg
ΦΩΤΟΓΡΑΦΙΕΣ-ΠΟΥ-ΤΡΑΒΗΧΤΗΚΑΝ-ΛΙΓΑ-ΔΕΥΤΕΡΟΛΕΠΤΑ-ΠΡΙΝ-ΣΥΜΒΕΙ-ΤΟ-ΜΟΙΡΑΙΟ.jpg (original uploaded)

Comment: Sorry I'm not clear. Open terminal and type `ll`. Then show the command you typed with all the output following it. Copy it to your clipboard and paste it into your question (not into comment section like you did).

Comment: Added, i hope can helps

Comment: Defenitelly this is not about Ubuntu. I think questions like this should be asked on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/. Probably you need some kind of function in your `functions.php` that is able to generate a list of all images which are found  within the site content.